# Dynamic video playlist in HTML5 and other

Tags: javascript, html, video, playlist

I'd like to know if with `HTML5` and `JavaScript` - and relative support in later browser versions, plus some server side technology `PHP` could I manage a dynamic video playlist.

I would like to play video1, video2, video3 (placed in a web server sub directory) and loop. I would like to then add a video (video4) and then system should play video1, video2, video3, video4 (loop).

With PHP I can easy add file video4 in sub directory but I don't know about a playlist loop in HTML5/ECMA/JavaScript.

It it possible and easy to implement?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This would be relatively easy to set up.

On the PHP side you would do the detection of what's in your subdirectory and based on that output the HTML so it's all in your page.

You could then start that HTML5 video with JQuery and use a callback to start the next one. If the callback is the final one then you start over again.

Relevant code samples:

In PHP get the files in the subdirectory with:

```
$dir = '/subdirectory';
$videoFileNames = scandir($dir);
// $videoFilesNames[0-...] is now the file names you can use to create the HTML
```

In JQuery you can start the video with:

```
 $('#videoId').get(0).play();
```

Catch the callback with:

```
$("#videoId").bind("ended", function() {
   // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an xml form that lists all the video sources and set title and such there, then call it in your HTML.  If you dont' know how to do this I can send over what mine looks like.